# Prove that function $f$ is identically $0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

$ f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ be a continuous function. Now, we define a function $g(x)$ such that: $ g(x)= f(x) \int_0^x f(t) \,dt$ .
 Prove that if $g$ is an non-increasing function then $ f$ is identically equal to $0$.

We can't apply  Leibniz integral rule cause we can't say $f(x)$ is differentiable. Please help me to proceed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $$h(x)=\frac 1 2\left (\int_0^xf(t)dt\right)^2$$
Then $$h^\prime(x)=f(x)\int_0^xf(t)dt=g(x)$$
By assumption, $g$ is non-increasing. Since $g(0)=0$, then $g(x)\geq 0$ for $x\leq 0$, and $g(x)\leq 0$ for $x\geq 0$.

Therefore $h$ has a global maximum at $x=0$. Since $h(0)=0$, we conclude that $h$ is identically zero. As a consequence, $\int_0^x f(t)dt=0$ for all $x$. Differentiate in $x$ to see that it implies that $f$ is identically zero as well.